# Yii how to get clean and pretty URL

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, yii, yii-extensions

I am newbie to Yii framework. I have uncommented the url manager in the config file and got a url scheme like this:

```
http://localhost/mysite/index.php/displayAll
```

I don't want the index.php in the url. So I want a url some thing like this

```
http://localhost/mysite/displayAll
```

To accomplish this, what should I do. I did play with the url manager and some htaccess, but nothing gone well.

Please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?mysite/(.*)$ /mysite/index.php/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 9):

In your .htaccess you should have this:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php
```

Then you have to add the urlManager component to your main config file:

```
array(
    ......
    'components'=>array(
        ......
        'urlManager'=>array(
            'urlFormat'=>'path',
            'showScriptName'=>false,
            'rules'=>array(
                'pattern1'=>'route1',
                'pattern2'=>'route2',
                'pattern3'=>'route3',
            ),
        ),
    ),
);
```

Notice the **'showScriptName'=>false**, this will hide 'index.php' from the generated URL.

To find everything about Yii's URL Manager check out this topic in Yii's documentation:
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.url

Comment: Good answer. This is more conventional way of doing it. Allthough Jon Lin's answer should work too!

Answer (score 0):

In httpd.conf look for,

```
     LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

(remove # from the begining of line if not already removed.)

```
              OR 
     In wamp click on wampserver-> Apache -> Apache Modules and enable rewrite_module.
```

Create .htaccess in directory where your index.php is, and paste following code:

```
IndexIgnore */*
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule . index.php
```

And in protected/config/main.php

```
 'urlManager' => array(
    'urlFormat' => 'path',
    'showScriptName' => false,
    'rules' => array(
       '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/view',
       '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
       '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
     ),
 ),
```

If still not getting clean url,goto virtual host config file "httpd-vhosts" incase of you are using it, and paste in your config,

```
 <Directory "C:/wamp/www">
    AllowOverride All 
 </Directory>
```

Comment: With Yii2 you should replace `\w+` with `[\w\-]+` in order to support hyphens/dashes in the controller and action names.

Answer (score 0):

On IIS 7, IIS 7.5, IIS 8, IIS 8.5, IIS 10

1. Make sure you have the **URL Rewrite module** installed. Can be found here: http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite
2. remove comment from **config/main.php** or **config/web.php**

   ```
       'urlManager' => [
       'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
       'showScriptName' => false,
       'rules' => [
       ],
   ],
   ```
3. Create new file in the web directory basic/web/**web.config** and add in **system.webServer**

   ```
   <directoryBrowse enabled="false" />

   <rewrite>
       <rules>
       <rule name="Hide Yii Index" stopProcessing="true">
           <match url="." ignoreCase="false" />
           <conditions>
           <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
           <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
           </conditions>
               <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" appendQueryString="true" />
       </rule> 
       </rules>
   </rewrite>
   ```

Example result: http://localhost/basic/web/site/contact