# 500 internal server error after enabling pretty url

Tags: php, .htaccess, yii2

After adding this `htaccess` in web folder:

```
RewriteEngine on
# If a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# Otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

and adding in components `config/web.php`

```
'urlManager' => [
    'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
    'showScriptName' => false,
    'enableStrictParsing' => false,
    'rules' => [
        // ...
    ],
],
```

then opening in the browser:

`http://localhost/myiiproj/site/login`

I have this error:

> **Internal Server Error**
>
> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was
>   unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server administrator at admin@example.com to inform
>   them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed
>   just before this error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server error
>   log.

Did I miss something in configuration? Or is there other configuration to make this work?

Comment: Are you using apache?
is rewrite_module enabled?

Comment: You should check the server error log, but `.` stands for 1 arbitrary character, you probably want `.*` for 0 or more characters.

Comment: @Aciety, yes , already enabled

Comment: I to had some problem while I hosted in linux hosting. but it worked in my local testing environment. so check your php version.

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26525320/enable-clean-url-in-yii2

Comment: You need to place your .htaccess file in /web directory in basic app (and /frontend/web for advanced). The original content of htaccess is correct.

Comment: yes I already put that in under web directory

Answer (score 1):

if you use apache server you must enable rewrite_module in httpd.conf,
You can find httpd.conf in C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.9\conf directory.
this is my directory, this directory may change therefore you must use your directory.Then you go line:

`#LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so`

and remove (#).You must change such as the following code.

`LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so`

save and close httpd.conf file.Restart your apache server.

Answer (score 0):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L] 
</IfModule>
```

here is a simple htaccess to convert pretty url
and make sure to enable mod_rewrite

or

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?mysite/(.*)$ /mysite/index.php/$1 [L]
```

from this post
[Yii how to get clean and pretty URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11807652/yii-how-to-get-clean-and-pretty-url)

Comment: .htaccess that you had created