# Changing pattern of url to accept username like facebook

Tags: php, regex, yii, yii-url-manager

I need to covert user profile link  from this
http://example.com/site/index?user_id=sami.yaqoub

To be like Facebook
http://example.com/sami.yaqoub

I changed the rules of config file to except that.

Config.php

```
<?php
..
 'urlManager' => array(
            'urlFormat' => 'path',
            'showScriptName' => false,
            'rules' => array(
                    '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/view',
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
                '<user:[a-zA-Z0-9_-]\w+>'=>'site/index',// here is the code 
            ),
        ),
...
?>
```

It worked with all words not contained any dot "." , so I changed it to be like this

```
 '<user:[a-zA-Z0-9_-.]\w+>'=>'site/index',// return error
```

But also not worked .
What is the best method in this case to except this formula
Name.anything

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In you regexp `[a-zA-Z0-9_-.]\w+` you can match things like `.helloworld` but not `hello.world` because you match the dot `.` character only in first position.

You should write it like that : `[a-zA-Z0-9_-.][\w.]+`.

I am not sure, but maybe Facebook does not allow special characters in first position such as dot or dash`.-`. In that case the correct answer would be : `[a-zA-Z0-9][\w.]+` or shorter `\w[\w.]+`

Note that `\w` in a regexp matches word characters. `\w` is equivalent to `[A-Za-z0-9_]`

Answer (score 1):

Try create a .htaccess file in root folder and paste this code below.

```
# if you have mod rewrite installed in your hosting space, you can enable pretty url for
# compressed css/js by uncommenting following lines

#RewriteEngine On
#Options FollowSymLinks
#RewriteRule   ^packs/(\w+)\.(css|js)   packs/jscsscomp.php?q=$1.$2 

Options +FollowSymlinks
Options -Indexes

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . index.php [L,QSA]

<Files .htaccess>
order allow,deny
deny from all
```

This might help also-> [Yii how to get clean and pretty URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11807652/yii-how-to-get-clean-and-pretty-url)

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you want to do is create a `Slug`.

Take a look [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-behaviors-sluggablebehavior.html) if you want to create it yourself or check any already made [plugins](https://github.com/zelenin/yii2-slug-behavior) that do it for you.