# Configure my index.php from root to open pages inside folder and sub-folder php

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

I am trying to configure my index.php from the document root to open the other files. I don't need to do that on the .htaccess
My file structure is the following:

```
/application
    /database
       /dbmanager.php
    /php
       index.php
       login.php
/models
/resources
    /css
       /master.css
    /js
       /general.js
    /img
       /logo.png
index.php
```

What I want is to configure so I can pick the files request from the index.php root to the application/php/ folders.
In my index.php from the document root I have this:

```
<?php


if (($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) == '/login') {
    require('application/php/login.php');
    exit();
} else {
    require('application/php/index.php');
    exit();
}

?>
```

Also, I don't want to appear the **application/php/login.php** on the link but only **/login**
My HTML link is :

```
<a href="<?php echo $domain; ?>login" >Login</a>
```

$domain is the full path domain of my localhost so I don't always write everything. In this case is: **"http://localhost:81/{project_name}"** and the **/login** will pick up the file on the folders.

**UPDATE:**

```
RewriteBase /application/php/

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f


RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ ./application/php/index.php

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ ./application/php/index.php

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ ./application/php/index.php
```

Comment: that's what you need .htaccess for! I doubt that's possible without

Comment: @Jeff Can you help me with the .htaccess? How to do that so I can call it well?  I edited my question with the htaccess code

Comment: this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30709741/rewrite-url-from-index-phppage-about-to-page?rq=1